# SPRING - Get current scope

Tags: spring

How can I access, throughout a Spring application, the current thread scope...

In other words, how can I identify if the current thread scope is a request or a system local thread ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with

```
if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) 
   // request thread
```

Comment: To answer to the question, how can we find other scope? If it's from different thread.